# Show Apple Contacts Birthdays in Google Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, ical, google-calendar

I have all my contacts on my iPhone including birthdays. Recently I switched to Google Calendar because of workplace requirements.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to display the birthdays from my iPhone contacts inside the Google Calendar app on my iPhone. It only displays the Birthdays Calendar from the Google contacts, but I don't want to keep two different contacts in sync.

It would also be useful to get these birthdays inside the Google calendar.

Comment: So it works on the Apple part, which is what this site is for. Next stop Google.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should transfer all your contatcts to Google and not sync it over iCloud...

Comment: The iPhone birthdays calendar is a "goody" you get when using your Apple device. It is created automatically and can't be exported or subscribed to. As @X_841 points out, you should copy your contacts to Google to get the that functionality in your Google Calendar.